# Design a heading with pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

I made a little Pen on CodePen to show the issue and I think it's the easiest if you have a look at it.

You can find it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRXRZg).

Basically I'm searching for a way to have pseudo elements before and after a heading, to display a 1px heigh line which comes from the sides and is interrupted by the text.

```
-------------------------------------- Text --------------------------------------
```

If the text is long (or the display small), the text will wrap in two lines. Then the left line will still be next to the beginning and the right part will stay next to the end.

```
------------------------------ More text that will cover
                                    multiple lines ------------------------------
```

My ideal would be something like this

```
______________________________ More text that will cover _________________________
                                    multiple lines
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to draw the line, and position it 50% from the top or bottom as a way to keep it in the center of the text, even if the text goes to 2 lines.

```css
h5 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
h5:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background: #000;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

span {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h5><span>This is<br>some text</span></h5>
```